# intellisense - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Olá

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em VB com dois formulários, o primeiro frmCadastroEndereco, para resgistrar endereços no banco de dados, outro de cadastro de clientes. Uso também um módulo (modEndereco) que deveria acessar os objetos do formulário frmCadastroEndereco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O textbox selecionado na imagem tem name = IDEnderecoTextBox

No entanto, quando uso o atalho ctrl+espaço, para escrever o código no módulo, o nome desde e de dos demais objetos não aparecem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Entretanto, se eu escrever o nome completo do objeto o Visual Studio reconhece que exite um textbox com o nome IDEnderecoTextBox no formulário frmCadastroEndereco

Agora, por que quando utilizo o atalho ctrl+espaço o nome do objeto não aparece?

Comment: o objeto está acessível por onde você está chamando ele? digo, ele está "público" para esse método aí?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza disso, pois, adiciono os TextBox pela toolbox. Mas quando eu digito o nome completo, sem utilizar o atalho, nenhum erro ocorre, se não estivesse como Public não daria para acessar mesmo digitando o nome corretamente.